# Perform macro for all open presentations

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I've the following code which I use to place a shape on the first slide of one my powerpoints.

```
Sub WriteToTextBox()
Dim tb As Shape
Dim sld As Slide
Dim pres As Presentation
Dim var1 As String


var1 = InputBox("Var1")
Set pres = ActivePresentation
Set sld = pres.Slides(1) 'Modify as needed

Set tb = sld.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 400, 400, 100, 50) 
tb.Name = "InsertShape"  
tb.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = var1

End Sub
```

I know want to perform this for all my open presentations. I tried to do this like this

```
Sub WriteToTextBoxALL()

Dim i as integer
Dim pptcount as integer

Dim tb As Shape
Dim sld As Slide
Dim pres As Presentation
Dim var1 As String

For i = 1 to pptcount

var1 = InputBox("Var1")
Set pres = ActivePresentation
Set sld = pres.Slides(1) 'Modify as needed

Set tb = sld.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 400, 400, 100, 50) 
tb.Name = "InsertShape"  
tb.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = var1

Next
End Sub
```

But I get an error. Anybody input on what im doing wrong?

Dear regards,

Marc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `pptcount`. I changed your code to this:

```
Sub WriteToTextBoxALL()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim pptcount As Integer

    Dim tb As Shape
    Dim sld As Slide
    Dim pres As Presentation
    Dim var1 As String

    pptcount = Application.Presentations.Count

    For i = 1 To pptcount
        Set pres = Application.Presentations(i)

        var1 = InputBox("Var1")
        Set sld = pres.Slides(1)

        Set tb = sld.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 400, 400, 100, 50)
        tb.Name = "InsertShape"
        tb.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = var1

    Next
End Sub
```

**Edit:**

For just drawing a normal border to your shape, add

```
tb.Line.Visible = True
```

---

[Explanation to with-statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx)

Comment: Thanks a lot Manu! Just another small question. If i want to include a border a shape I made I assume I have to work with "with and end with" statements. But i'm not sure on which element to call this? Suggestions...?

Comment: updated the answer. i added a link to explain what with-statements are ;)